# Vocalist in "Edward & Mrs. Simpson"

Tags: edward-and-mrs.-simpson

I've recently been watching the 1978 TV miniseries "Edward & Mrs. Simpson." The vocalist that sings the recurring theme and other songs is listed as "Jenny Wren" but sounds quite a lot like Julie Andrews. You can listen to the theme song on YouTube.  "Jenny Wren" is the name of a character in the Charles Dickens novel *Our Mutual Friend*. I can't find listings for "Jenny Wren" in any other productions or recordings.  Did Julie Andrews use a different name when singing in "Edward & Mrs. Simpson" to avoid antagonizing the British Royal Family or for other reasons?

Comment: Well, there *was* a singer called [Jenny Wren](http://www.historywebsite.co.uk/articles/InBetweenTimes/Page9.htm), though she doesn't really sound like that.

Comment: She doesn't sound anything like Julie Andrews... I mean, I get why you might think that, but I don't think that's her.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the singer was indeed ***[Jenny Wren](http://www.discogs.com/artist/849955-Jenny-Wren?filter_anv=0&subtype=Vocals&type=Credits)*** (Real name Jenny Allen). Jenny recorded two records for Fontana; [Chasing My Dreams All Over Town](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1o8lfAFey-M) and [The Merry-Go-Round Is Slowing You Down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8WwkbwVjvk) as well as providing the songs for the later TV show:

> 15 year-old Jenny Allen first came to notice in Wolverhampton in 1964
>   when she was backed by the group Les Jondors and apparently got her
>   break when one of Fontana's A&R men, Jack Baverstock heard her.
>
> in 1965 (whilst still a pupil at the Sir Gilbert Claughton School in
>   Dudley) she changed her name to Jenny Wren and signed a recording
>   contract with Fontana.  She only released two records on Fontana,
>   Chasing My Dreams All Over Town and The Merry-Go-Round Is Slowing You
>   Down.

There's also a mention of her on this [local history](http://www.historywebsite.co.uk/articles/InBetweenTimes/Page9.htm) site.

---

It may interest you to know that she reinvented herself in the 1980s, teaching at Croydon College of Music, providing the vocals for Helen Mirren's "[Painted Lady](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok1HI_PzLQU)" and had minor success with a duet with [Pat Benetar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP1wnzqsGd0) under the name Jenny **Darren**. Jenny <s>Wren</s> <s>Allen</s> Darren is still gigging to this day.